# About a kind of real sequences $z_{k}$ making an implication true

Tags: real-analysis, functions

What kind of real sequences $(z_{k})$ making the following implication true:
$x_{k}=O(y_{k}/z_{k})$ imply $y_{k}=O(x_{k})$

where $O$ is the big $O$ notation. Here all these sequences are never zero for all indices $k$.

Comment: Wait, did you mean $x_k=O(y_k)$ for the implication or $y_k=O(x_k)$?

Comment: @QC_QAOA: The second one.

Comment: @QC_QAOA: What about the case where all these sequences are never zero for all indices

Comment: @Helena, if you really ask $y_{k}=O(x_{k})$, then this is weird. For $x_{k}=O(y_{k})$ is much more plausible.

Comment: @user284331: Yes. I am asking about this exactly.

Comment: If $x_k\sim y_k$ then $0<\epsilon<|z_k|<M$ should be sufficient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: New answer as the original question was modified so that the sequences could not be identically zero.

---

There are no real sequences which make it true in general. For example, set

$$y_k=kx_kz_k$$

Then it is surely true that

$$x_k=O\left(\frac{y_k}{z_k}\right)$$

for any $z_k$. This is because

$$x_k\leq kx_k =1\cdot \left(\frac{kx_k z_k}{z_k}\right)=1\cdot\left(\frac{y_k}{z_k}\right)$$

is true for all $k\geq 1$. However, it is obviously false that

$$y_k=O(x_k)$$

as this would imply that there exists $c$ such that

$$y_k=kx_k\leq cx_k$$

$$k\leq c$$

for all but a finite number of $k$. This is obviously false. We conclude that there is no sequence $z_k$ such that the following implication is always true: $x_{k}=O(y_{k}/z_{k})$ implies $y_{k}=O(x_{k})$

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**

**The result should be $x_{k}=O(y_{k})$:**

If there were $\epsilon_{0}>0$ and $K$ such that $|z_{k}|\geq\epsilon_{0}$ for all $k\geq K$, then it will do.

Comment: Can you give this proof by using constants appeared in the definition of the big $O$ notation.

Comment: From $x_{k}=O(y_{k}/z_{k})$, we find an $M>0$ such that $|x_{k}|\leq M|y_{k}/z_{k}|$ for large $k$. For $k$ large enough, by assumption $|z_{k}|\geq\epsilon_{0}$, so for these $k$, $|x_{k}|\leq\dfrac{M}{\epsilon_{0}}|y_{k}|$, this means that $x_{k}=O(y_{k})$.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: Isn't this proving something different than the original question? Namely  $x_k=O(y_k)$ instead of $y_k=O(x_k)$.

Comment: @QC_QAOA: Can we find sufficient conditions to get this implication.